# Configuring repository settings and labels using YAML

Tags: github

Managing a large number of repositories in GitHub can be challenging. When we decide to introduce a new label or update a setting, manually making these changes can be extremely time-consuming. While company-wide management may offer a partial solution, the problem persists when dealing with multiple accounts and profiles.

Is there a way to modify settings and labels from configuration files (in `{repository}/.github/` folder as YAML files)? Is it possible to create a workflow for updating configuration files and applying those changes automatically? If so, how can this be achieved?

There are some similar efforts available online, but we haven't found an official source that specifically addresses this. Our idea is to create a repository where we store the settings, and in every other repository, we would only need to reference this one repository containing configurations to enforce the settings. We would also be content if the configurations were stored in files, and we updated them one by one. Currently, the graphical interface is unmanageable.

Comment: If you can have one repo with shared config in, you could potentially then have an Actions workflow in it to propagate changes to other repos (all in org, or maybe from a block/allow list in the same repo) via the GH API.